# Positioned Widgets on SingleChildScrollView - Differences between smartphones - Flutter

Tags: scroll, dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-positioned

I'm developing a small game with a scrollable map and levels.
I have a scrollable map in a *SingleChildScrollView*. 
I want to put my *Positioned* Widgets (my levels) on my map.

I used this formula to find map resolution: **width_map/height_map**.
I used this formula to find left distance: **MediaQuery_width * resolution_map * custom_width_position.**
I used this formula to find height distance: **MediaQuery_height * resolution_map * custom_height_position.**

```
Positioned(
          left: width * sizeMap * level['width'],
          top: height * sizeMap * level['height'],
          child: ...
)
```

This formula with different smartphones has different result => the levels are not on the identical place on map (they are near but places not corresponding).
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using 


      debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;

p.s. you need to add 


    import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

Comment: Thanks guy. I've understand my error. Map are different on same devices because I didn't manage width of my image.